# Can't open jupyter notebook in docker

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pytorch

I am trying to open the jupyter notebook in a container, but I just came cross this situation:

```
[I 10:01:25.051 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 10:01:25.051 NotebookApp] http://8c1eb91f0492:8888/?token=7671a7abe557349c8d8ad1cbf207702451925efd2c27c84e
[I 10:01:25.051 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:01:25.051 NotebookApp]
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://8c1eb91f0492:8888/?token=7671a7abe557349c8d8ad1cbf207702451925efd2c27c84e&token=7671a7abe557349c8d8ad1cbf207702451925efd2c27c84e
```

As you can see the url is the container ID, I tried many solutions, like the ip setting. All don't help at all. Could someone give the hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look here: https://forums.docker.com/t/using-localhost-for-to-access-running-container/3148/2

Comment: Make sure the port is exposed and replace the hostname in the URL with `localhost`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Try using localhost step by step :**

1 - Launch the following command :

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook
```

2 - Copy/paste the url URL into your browser : http://e6ef92c5e5d6:8888/?token=...

3 - Replace the hostname by localhost : http://localhost:8888/?token=...

It worked for me :

```
[I 03:22:51.414 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=... (172.17.0.1) 0.97ms
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and also I changed to the new port as the 8888 is always occupied by other service.

Answer (score 2):

when you run the container use `--net=host` option is used to make the programs inside the Docker container look like they are running on the host itself, so you dont need port forwarding Example:

```
docker run --net=host --name  container_wanted_name --gpus all -it -v /local_dir/:/workspace/container_dir container_initial_name
```

then inside container open jupyter using the command:

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888
```

it will give a link such this one:
http://hostname:8888/?token=413ec5d51ebde8318e76bed1030b79309ee15e342507623a

use the link to access the container but replace `hostname` with `localhost`

Comment: This worked for me.  They should include in the official documentation.  I'm on Debian 11, if that mattered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by **@lescaudr** works good. I have learned something new from there. If you use this command e.g.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 10000:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook
```

Then, when you will get a link like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=536855ec2931357c60f6a03ef413be21faaa2d8f863c7ty6
```

When you copy-paste the above link in your browser then just change the port from **8888** to **10000** and it works as well: